# why is re-find returning a vector with two elements?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

When using re-find in this way:

```
(re-find #"(\d{3})" "abc1245")
```

I get:

```
["124" "124"]
```

when I expect just one value. What's going on?

Comment: BTW to exclude the group from capturing but leave the grouping semantics you can use the syntax (?:\d{3}) .. you don't need it here, but it is useful in many other cases. Like (?:\d+|NaN)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the parentheses create a regex "group".  See

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-find

for examples.  Here's the difference:

```
(re-find #"(\d{3})"  "abc1245")     => ["124" "124"]   ; #1
(re-find  #"\d{3}"   "abc1245")     =>  "124"          ; #2
(re-seq   #"\d{3}"   "abc1245")     => ("124")         ; #3
(re-seq   #"\d{3}"   "abc12345678") => ("123" "456")   ; #4
```

So, #1 gives you both the result and the "group result". #2 gives you just the matched substring.

#3 gives you a sequence of all matches.  Since there are only 4 digits, the remaing "5" isn't enough to match 3 digits.

#4 gives 8 digits total, so we get `"123"` and `"456"` as matches, with 7 & 8 leftover since we only want triples of digits.

Comment: Great! I understand now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Round brackets in your regex `(\d{3})` define a capture group, so `re-find` returns the whole match and all the match groups.
As per [re-find doc](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-find):

> Returns the next regex match, if any, of string to pattern, using
>   java.util.regex.Matcher.find().  Uses re-groups to return the groups.

If you remove the brackets - you'll get only one match as you expected:

```
=> (re-find #"\d{3}" "abc1245")
=> "124"
=> (re-find #"(\d{3})" "abc1245")
=> ["124" "124"]
```

You can check it yourself in this [online repl](https://repl.it/@achikin/Regex-brackets).